# Continuity of Complex function and restrictions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

I am trying the following question but am stuck at finding the restriction:
Prove that $f(z)=1/z^2$ is continuous at $z_0= 1+2i$

Solution: I am trying the use epsilon-delta proof and got it down to: $\frac{|-3+4i-z^2|}{|(-3+4i)||z|^2}$ $\leq$ $\frac{|z-(-1+2i)||z+(-1-2i)|}{|(-3+4i)||z|^2}$. But now I am having trouble in finding a restriction on $|z+(-1-2i)|$ and dealing with the denominator

Comment: Are you required to do it from first principles? It will me much easier to note that $z^2$, being a polynomial, is continuous everywhere, and $w\mapsto 1/w$ is continuous at every $w\ne 0$ (and a composition of continuous functions is continuous). If you need to argue for the latter, write it as $x+yi \mapsto \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}i$ and argue that the components of this are continuous as _real_ functions and that this suffices to prove complex continuity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, we have use the epsilon delta definition

Answer (score 1):

When subtracting quotients, bring to a common denominator: 
$$\left|\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z_0^2}\right| = \frac{|z_0^2-z^2|}{|z|^2|z_0|^2}=|z_0-z|\frac{|z_0+z|}{|z|^2|z_0|^2}$$
I separated the factor of $|z_0-z|$ because it's the one we control directly by choosing $\delta$. The other stuff we can control indirectly via the triangle inequality. Ideally, we'd like to bound it by some number. In order to do this:

1. bound $|z_0+z|$ from above.
2. bound $|z|$ from below
3. bound $|z_0|$ from below

Well the last part is clear: you know what $|z_0|$  is. Use the triangle inequality for 1, and reverse triangle inequality for 2.